# Case statement with "where in" clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause

I have a scenario whereby I need to use multiple values in my where clause if a param passed to the query is 99999 otherwise I just use the param itself. I am using "IN" as part of the where clause but I get the following error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'".
Any one provide an alternative to the incorrect query that will get me the results I need?

```
DECLARE @IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM decimal (18,0)
 SET @IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM = 99999

SELECT 
    n.id,
    n.headline,
    n.news_type_id
FROM news n
WHERE n.news_type_id IN
CASE WHEN @IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM = 99999 THEN (1,2,3,4,5)
ELSE
(@IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM)
END
```

Comment: The core issue is that 1) `(1,2,..)` is not an expression and thus cannot be the result of `CASE`; and, supporting 2) `IN` requires a fixed tuple (not an expression of one which is not possible) - therefor, it will never work like that. If the problem is more complex (i.e. there are different values other than 99999 to worry about), make sure to indicate that information as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
DECLARE @IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM decimal (18,0)
 SET @IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM = 99999

SELECT 
    n.id,
    n.headline,
    n.news_type_id
FROM news n
WHERE (n.news_type_id IN ('1','2','3','4','5') AND @IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM = 99999) 
   OR (n.news_type_id = @IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM AND @IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM <> 99999)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an IF statement:

```
DECLARE @IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM decimal (18,0)
 SET @IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM = 99999

IF (@IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM = 99999) 
    SELECT 
        n.id,
        n.headline,
        n.news_type_id
    FROM news n
    WHERE n.news_type_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
ELSE
    SELECT 
        n.id,
        n.headline,
        n.news_type_id
    FROM news n
    WHERE n.news_type_id = @IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM
```

Comment: Thanks John, I will give this one to Goat as he beat you to it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression to return a value to be subsequently tested, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    n.id,
    n.headline,
    n.news_type_id
FROM news n
WHERE CASE
  WHEN @IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM = 99999 THEN
    CASE WHEN n.news_type_id IN (1,2,3,4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  WHEN @IPD_NEWS_TYPE_PARAM = n.news_type_id THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END = 1
```